Unable to send image to a face recognization module through express js backend req to the module
I am trying to send a image file in a request from express js backend to the python face reconization module which is not working all codes and errors is given below. But when sending the request from postman(i am using hoppscotch in place of postman) to the python module it is working fine. All screenshot is also shared below.


Controller part for the endpoint->
//Sending req to ml module
export const getFaceDetails= async( req , res )=>{
    const photo = req.file;

    

    try {

        const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', photo.buffer);

        console.log(formData);

        // Make the POST request to the face recognition module
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/detect', formData, {
            headers: {
                "content-type":"multipart/form-data" // Set appropriate headers for multipart/form-data
            }
        });

        // Handle response from the face recognition module
        res.status(200).json(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending image to face recognition module:', error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Error processing the image');
    }
}

Route part

import {  getFaceDetails } from '../controllers/Hackathon.js';


const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
});

HackathonRoutes.post("/face",upload.single("image"),getFaceDetails)


flask_main.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import cv2
import numpy as np
from retinaface import RetinaFace
from deepface import DeepFace
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize known face embeddings (from the database)
known_faces = []
known_profiles = ['ritika.jpg', 'shubham.jpg', 'kuldeep.jpg', 'anurag.jpg', 'chaudhary.jpg']


# Pre-compute embeddings for known profiles
for profile_image in known_profiles:
    img = cv2.imread(profile_image)
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    face_embedding = DeepFace.represent(img_rgb, model_name="ArcFace", enforce_detection=False)
    if len(face_embedding) > 0:
        known_faces.append(face_embedding[0]['embedding'])

@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def detect_faces():
    # Check if an image is provided
    
    if 'image' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No image provided"}), 400

    # Load the uploaded image
    file = request.files['image']
    print(file)

    # image=file.read()

    # KP change1

    # file_bytes = np.frombuffer(file.read(), np.uint8)
    # image = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # if image is None:
    #     return jsonify({"error": "Failed to decode image"}), 400

    #KP change 2

    image = np.frombuffer(file.read(), np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    #Original Code

    # image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(file.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Use RetinaFace to detect faces
    faces = RetinaFace.detect_faces(image)
    if len(faces) == 0:
        return jsonify({"message": "No faces detected"}), 200

    matches = []
    
    # Process each detected face in the group image
    for i, (key, face_data) in enumerate(faces.items()):
        # Get face bounding box
        bbox = face_data['facial_area']
        face_crop = image[bbox[1]:bbox[3], bbox[0]:bbox[2]]  # Crop the detected face
        
        # Convert to RGB for DeepFace
        face_crop_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(face_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        
        # Get face embedding using DeepFace (ArcFace model)
        face_in_group = DeepFace.represent(face_crop_rgb, model_name="ArcFace", enforce_detection=False)
        
        if len(face_in_group) > 0:
            unknown_embedding = face_in_group[0]['embedding']  # Extract embedding
            
            # Compare detected face with known faces
            for j, known_embedding in enumerate(known_faces):
                # Calculate cosine similarity
                similarity = np.dot(known_embedding, unknown_embedding) / (np.linalg.norm(known_embedding) * np.linalg.norm(unknown_embedding))
                
                # Set a threshold for matching
                if similarity > 0.4:
                    matches.append({
                        "detected_face": f"Face {i}",
                        "matched_profile": known_profiles[j],
                        "similarity": round(similarity, 2)
                    })
                    
    # Return the matched profiles
    if len(matches) > 0:
        return jsonify({"matches": matches}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "No matching faces found"}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Backend Error
Error sending image to face recognition module: Request failed with status code 400

Python log
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2024 11:54:10] "POST /detect HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2024 11:55:50] "POST /detect HTTP/1.1" 400 -

